# How can I determine the child class name from abstract parent class in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, abstract-class

I'm creating 4 ActiveRecord models that all inherit from the same base class. Currently, each of the 4 models has a belongs to relationship defined like this:

```
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'ChildClass1'
```

I'd like to pull this out into the base class with something along the lines of:

```
belongs_to :parent, :class_name => self.class_name
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused; the child class has a self-referential belongs-to association with itself?

Comment: ^^ I am very confused with this as well.  Perhaps rather than using inheritance, you should consider using mix-ins with modules.  Some more clarity on why would are using inheritance would be helpful to guide you to the correct approach.

Comment: I didn't write the code. I'm just writing the tests so that I can refactor the code with some confidence ;) The self-referential belongs-to is no where near the ugliest dragon to slay in here. You should see the 8 classes that share all but 1 line of code between them. It's ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the [`inherited`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited) hook:

```
class BaseClass
  def self.inherited(child_class)
    child_class.class_eval do
      belongs_to :parent, :class_name => child_class.name
    end
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: I love it. The only thing I decided to change was to add a call to `super` so that ActiveRecord's inherited method is called. Thanks Uri!